# ODBC Connection String

Tags: visual-c++, odbc

here is one VC++ ODBC Connection string, it is Unicode. How to make it generic? eg: I can input user name, password for different database.

```
SQLDriverConnect (sqlconnectionhandle, 
             NULL, 
             L"Driver={SQL Server};Server=123.1.78.100, 1433;Database=DB1;Uid=user123;Pwd=pw123;",
             SQL_NTS, 
             retconstring, 
             1024, 
             NULL,
             SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)
```

I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
string serverIp = "123.1.78.100, 1433";
string db_name = "DB1";
string user_id = "uesr123"
string pwd = "pw123";


string ss;
            ss.append("Driver={SQL Server};Server=");
            ss.append(serverIP);
            ss.append(";Database=");
            ss.append(dbName);
            ss.append(";Uid=");
            ss.append(uId);
            ss.append(";Pwd=");
            ss.append(pw);
            ss.append(";");

SQLDriverConnect (sqlconnectionhandle, 
             NULL, 
             (wchar_t*)ss.c_str(),
             SQL_NTS, 
             retconstring, 
             1024, 
             NULL,
             SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)
```

Comment: Whats went wrong in your code for generic connection making? Is there any kind of error? If so please append error message.

Comment: Error message is "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Comment: That mean you didn't created a database with that name... Before making connection to the database, create it. And try it.

Comment: Did you try the Generic method with sample of data used in the specific method? Did that also shows error?

Comment: the connectionString pattern, L##s, works, but I want to build a function which allows user to type db_name,ip,username and pw.

Comment: Sorry , i didn't get what you mean by this thing "the connectionString pattern, L##s, works,"...The function you written was fine. Dose user have give name and pswd which already exist, or you will create it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this: (while the database mentioned for connection is exist there.) It worked fine.

```
String ss;
            ss =  ("Driver={SQL Server};Server=");
            ss = ss + (serverIp);
            ss = ss + (";Database=");
            ss = ss + (db_name);
            ss = ss + (";Uid=");
            ss = ss + (uId);
            ss = ss + (";Pwd=");
            ss = ss + (pwd);
            ss = ss + (";");
```

Ensure about creation of database with name... Before making connection to the database